# Erro upload para outro servidor

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Estou tentando gravar algumas imagens em outro servidor apontando o IP e a pasta, no meu código PHP apontei o caminho da pasta `$_UP['pasta'] = '\\\\172.23.25.4\\\manutencao\\';`e ocorre o seguinte erro abaixo:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(\172.23.25.4\manutencao\1415978389.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/Sistemas/celu/public_html/souza/MANUTENCAO/projetos/AD-ipco-cod-01/fontes/cadastro/cadastro.php on line 126 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpEQFSvN' to '\172.23.25.4\manutencao\1415978389.jpg' ... on line 126 Não foi possível enviar o arquivo, tente novamente

Seu eu apontador ao caminho da pasta local, funciona normal, mas se apontar o caminho da pasta para outro servidor ocorre esse erro.

Concedi as permissões de pasta e usuário conforme as minhas pesquisa.

---

Criei um novo arquivo para teste e agora ocorre erro na função ftp_put()segue o erro

**CONETADO NO SERVIDOR 172.23.25.4, COM O USUARIO teste Warning: ftp_put(): Could not create file. in /home/SistemasInternos/cel/public_html/jbarbin/upload/teste2/ftp_envia.php on line 28
FTP upload has failed!**

segue o codigo

```
<form action="ftp_envia.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input name="file" type="file" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Abaixo o codigo php

```
<?php
ftp_server = "172.23.25.4";
$ftp_user_name = "teste";
$ftp_user_pass = "123456";
$destination_file = "/home/teste";
$source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name <br>"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "CONETADO NO SERVIDOR $ftp_server, COM O USUARIO $ftp_user_name";
}

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file,  FTP_ASCII); 

// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
    echo "<br>FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
    echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: Verifica se tem permissão a essa pasta via código, se não tiver, dê acesso a ela.

Comment: ja dei acesso a pasta e ocorre o mesmo erro

Comment: vc consegue acessar esse diretório via explorer ou browser?

Comment: consigo acessar normal via explorer e browser ..

Comment: Por acaso esse endereço remoto que eu assumo estar podendo ser acessado via rede com sucesso, é um PC com Windows? Pergunto porque tive o mesmo problema com a VM na qual uso o Linux Mint (baseado no Ubuntu) e enquanto eu não edite o fstab montando o path dessa pasta compartilhada (que no meu caso é uma partição inteira) não conseguia sequer criar um novo arquivo, quando mais fazer um upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido o problema, utilizei o seguinte código abaixo: 
referencia:http://wbruno.com.br/php/upload-de-arquivo-ftp-php/

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
//var_dump( $_FILES );//apenas para debug

    $servidor = 'x.x.x.x';
    $caminho_absoluto = '/home/teste/';
    $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];

    $con_id = ftp_connect($servidor) or die( 'Não conectou em: '.$servidor );
    ftp_login( $con_id, 'xxxx', 'xxx' );


    $enviado = ftp_put( $con_id, $caminho_absoluto.$arquivo['name'], $arquivo['tmp_name'], FTP_BINARY );

    if ($enviado){
        echo "Arquivo Enviando com sucesso para o Servidor: ". $servidor . "<br>Caminho do arquivo FTP ". $caminho_absoluto;
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="arquivo" />
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você não pode usar `move_uploaded_file` para carregar um ficheiro para um servidor remoto.
A maneira mais fácil de conseguir isso é usando as funções de FTP nativas do PHP.

```
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";
$ftp_user = "o_seu_username";
$ftp_pass = "a_sua_password";

$file = "path/para/o/ficheiro.txt";
$remote_file = "ficheiro.txt";

// Criar ligação
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Não conseguiu conectar com $ftp_server"); 

// Ir para a pasta onde quer carregar o ficheiro
ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/www/site/caminho/para/a/pasta');


// Efectuar login no FTP
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
    // Carregar ficheiro para servidor remoto
    if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
       echo "Carregado com sucesso de $file\n";
    } else {
       echo "Ocorreu um problema no carregamento de $file\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "Não foi possível conectar como $ftp_user\n";
}

// Fechar conexão
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Nota: Este código não foi testado

Se ocorrer algum erro, é possível que o servidor remoto tenha algum tipo de firewall e para isso use o seguinte código:

```
// Ligar modo passivo
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
```

Comment: obrigado, vou postar meu código aqui pra você ver .

Answer (score 0):

move_upload_file serve somente no caso do uso de um "uploaded file".
No seu caso:
1-verificar o direito de acceso
2- Usar copy()

Exemplo (php.net):

```
        <?php
           $file = 'example.txt';
           $newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

          if (!copy($file, $newfile))
            {
                echo "falha ao copiar $file...\n";
           }
        ?>
```

$file pode ser um URL e $newfile tamben.
Cuidado: copy() não va criar a pasta!