# Upload de arquivo com php

Tags: php, upload

Estou  usando o seguinte codigo :

```
$uploaddir = '../vagas/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['img']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Arquivo válido e enviado com sucesso.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possível ataque de upload de arquivo!\n";
}

echo 'Aqui está mais informações de debug:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";
```

O HTML está assim

```
<input type="file" name="img" id="img">
```

O erro que apresenta é 
Possível ataque de upload de arquivo!
Aqui está mais informações de debug:Array
(
    [img] => Array
        (
            [name] => download.jpeg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpOPe968
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 5555
        )

)

Porém não esta realizando o upload, ja dei chmos na pasta do servidor mas mesmo assim...
Como posso resolver?
E se possível como poderia renomear o arquivo ?
Obrigado

Comment: Se não tiver o multi-part no form ele não envia o arquivo.

Comment: ok coloquei mas memo assim nada

Comment: No `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)` não deveria estar enviando `$_FILES['img']['tmp_name']` ao invés de `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` ?

Comment: como Thyago não entendi a alteração sugerida

Comment: vc precisa usar o mesmo que esta no form, no `$_FILES`, no form está `img` e no `$_FILES` está `userfile`, use @+usuario para notificar ele.

Comment: a sim, ja arrumei, mas sem sucesso....

Comment: Bom, dentro do que nos passou até agora, postei uma resposta para melhor visualização do código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após muita pesquisa encontrei um script na web que resolveu

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="recebe_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>Arquivo</label>
  <input type="file" name="arquivo" />

  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
// Pasta onde o arquivo vai ser salvo
$_UP['pasta'] = 'uploads/';
// Tamanho máximo do arquivo (em Bytes)
$_UP['tamanho'] = 1024 * 1024 * 2; // 2Mb
// Array com as extensões permitidas
$_UP['extensoes'] = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif');
// Renomeia o arquivo? (Se true, o arquivo será salvo como .jpg e um nome único)
$_UP['renomeia'] = false;
// Array com os tipos de erros de upload do PHP
$_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
$_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite do PHP';
$_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho especifiado no HTML';
$_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
$_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo';
// Verifica se houve algum erro com o upload. Se sim, exibe a mensagem do erro
if ($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] != 0) {
  die("Não foi possível fazer o upload, erro:" . $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['arquivo']['error']]);
  exit; // Para a execução do script
}
// Caso script chegue a esse ponto, não houve erro com o upload e o PHP pode continuar
// Faz a verificação da extensão do arquivo
$extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['arquivo']['name'])));
if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes']) === false) {
  echo "Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: jpg, png ou gif";
  exit;
}
// Faz a verificação do tamanho do arquivo
if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['arquivo']['size']) {
  echo "O arquivo enviado é muito grande, envie arquivos de até 2Mb.";
  exit;
}
// O arquivo passou em todas as verificações, hora de tentar movê-lo para a pasta
// Primeiro verifica se deve trocar o nome do arquivo
if ($_UP['renomeia'] == true) {
  // Cria um nome baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com extensão .jpg
  $nome_final = md5(time()).'.jpg';
} else {
  // Mantém o nome original do arquivo
  $nome_final = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
}

// Depois verifica se é possível mover o arquivo para a pasta escolhida
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final)) {
  // Upload efetuado com sucesso, exibe uma mensagem e um link para o arquivo
  echo "Upload efetuado com sucesso!";
  echo '<a href="' . $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final . '">Clique aqui para acessar o arquivo</a>';
} else {
  // Não foi possível fazer o upload, provavelmente a pasta está incorreta
  echo "Não foi possível enviar o arquivo, tente novamente";
}
?>
```

A pagina WEB é [BLOG thiagobelem](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/upload-de-arquivos-com-php/)

Comment: Bom dia Amigo, caso precisar realizar um upload para outro servidor, segue o link   http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40709/15776

Comment: Não é o caso, mas mesmo assim obrigado e bom conhecer.....

Comment: Augusto, que bom que consegui resolver, mas para te falar a verdade, este script que postou tem a mesma funcionalidade do que eu e o @Edilson postamos, quase certeza que o problema estava no caminho que, neste script postado por você está assim: `$_UP['pasta'] = 'uploads/';` Apenas para constar, estes esquemas de caminho absoluto e relativo sempre dá bucha e acredito que este que era o problema final.

Answer (score 5):

Aparentemente o único problema que vejo nesse teu script é o fato de não teres especificado no *name* correto do arquivo temporário:

Está:

```
$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']
```

Deveria ser:

```
$_FILES['img']['tmp_name']
```

O resto são pequenos detalhes. Vejo também que estás a usar o mesmo exemplo da página do *[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)*, por isso aproveito deixar uma explicação.

No formulário *html*, deve-se especificar o tipo de codificação dos dados enviados à partir do *enctype*.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
    <input name="img" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

No script responsável por essa requisição, deve-se especificar o atributo `name` do *input* do tipo *file* na variável _$*FILES*, tanto para o *name* como também para o *tmp_name*.

Variável *$_FILES*:

- Nome local do ficheiro : *$_FILES['img']['name']*
- Nome temporário do ficheiro armazenado no servidor: *$_FILES['img']['tmp_name']*

Direitos no diretório:

- 0755: Todos os direitos para o proprietário, ler e escrever para outros.

Para o script responsável pela requisição:

```
if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){
    $uploaddir = file_exists('../vagas/') ? '../vagas/' : mkdir('../vagas/', 0755, true);
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['img']['name']);
    $permissao = (is_dir($uploaddir) && chmod($uploaddir, 0755)) ? true : die("A pasta de envio nao existe");
    echo '<pre>';
    if($permissao  && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "Ficheiro valido, e enviado.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Erro: Ficheiro nao enviado!\n";
    }

    echo 'Informacao de debugging:';
    print_r($_FILES);

    print "</pre>";
}
```

---

**Algumas referências:**

- [move_uploaded_file - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)
- [upload_post_method - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)
- [chmod - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)
- [mkdir - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Comment: amigo esta me retornando isto : A pasta de envio nao existe

Comment: e os diretórios estão com permissão 777

Comment: Experimenta antes criar a pasta manualmente.

Comment: ela ja foi  criada manualmente .....

Comment: Havia alguns erros de escrita no meu código de exemplo, experimenta novamente. Se retornar novamente erro na primeira tentativa, é só atualizar a página.

Comment: amigo mesmo assim não funcionou, porem achei uma solução em uma pg da web, irei postar... Obrigado

Comment: É realmente estranho, porque aqui está a funcionar normalmente.

Comment: tambem achei pois em um outro projeto trabalhei com um script semelhante e estava ok

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="img" id="img"><br />
 <input type="submit" name="img_ok" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

PHP

```
if($_POST["img_ok"]) {

    $tempname = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"]; // 
    $new_name = "nova_imagem"; // Novo nome do arquivo
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["img"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // Pega extensão de arquivo e converte em caracteres minúsculos.      
    $folder = "./vagas"; // Pasta onde será armazenada a imagem.

    if(!file_exists($folder)) { // Verifica se a pasta já existe.
        mkdir($folder, 0777, TRUE); // Cria a pasta.
        chmod($folder, 0777); // Seta a pasta como modo de escrita.
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder."/".$new_name.".".$extension)) { // Move arquivo para a pasta em questão e com o novo nome.
        echo "Arquivo válido e enviado com sucesso.\n";
    } else echo "Possível ataque de upload de arquivo!\n";
}
```

Comment: ele me retornou Possível ataque de upload de arquivo! @+Thyago ThySoft