# Enviar arquivo para servidor remoto com PHP

Tags: php, linux

Tenho um sistema em PHP que desenvolvi e coloquei online em meu servidor na DigitalOcean, o site possui duas partes, a que os visitantes vão acessar e a área de administração onde eu gerencio este site e coloco o conteúdo ao qual os usuários terão acesso.

Deixei a área de administração em minha máquina local por questões de segurança já que apenas eu a acesso e não teria motivos para coloca-la online, fiz a conexão com o banco de dados que fica na DigitalOcean com a área de admin que está na minha máquina local e tudo funciona perfeitamente, só que tem um problema ao qual não sei como resolver.

Necessito quando cadastro informações enviar imagens dos itens que eu cadastro no sistema, ai que ta o problema, eu n sei como fazer, e fazer de forma segura a postagem dessas imagens da minha máquina local para o meu servidor Linux na DigitalOcean, atualmente eu envio essas imagens fazendo commits no meu repositório Git local para o meu servidor git remoto, oque é extremamente errado e faz com que eu tenha q ficar dando commit a todo momento quando cadastro novos itens simplesmente para que as imagens sejam enviadas.

Como posso fazer o envio dessas imagens usando a linguagem PHP de forma segura para o meu servidor remoto?

**OBS: Meu servidor na DigitalOcean eu só acesso ele via SSH do meu terminal linux na máquina local, teria que ser uma forma que permita esse upload com um servidor SSH ativo no servidor remoto**

Comment: Ela tem algum serviço de guarda de arquivos, assim como a Amazon tem o S3?? Se sim, deve ter alguma documentação sobre como usar a API para upload.

Comment: você já tentou com cURL?

Comment: sinceramente não sei te responder, veja, quando eu faço o upload via git os argivos são enviados para o meu servidor DO, oque eu quero é fazer isso mas n via GIT e sim via formulário na minha área de administração na minha máquina local e que esse arquivo va para uma pasta la na minha máquina como qualquer outro arquivo, são apenas imagens JPG

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro upload para outro servidor](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40493/erro-upload-para-outro-servidor)

Comment: esse exemplo que vc citou n se aplica ao meu caso, tenho um servidor linux que só pode ser acessado via SSH, essa solução que foi apresentada lá nessa postagem não funciona comigo, eu testei, caso vc teste e obtenha um resultado diferente por favor compartilhe aqui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O [rsync](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Transferindo-arquivos-com-o-rsync), para Gnu/Linux, efetua sincronização entre pastas, assim, sempre que você adicionar imagens em sua pasta local elas serão enviadas para o diretório remoto. É possível ainda configurá-lo afim de evitar duplicidade e fazer backup.

Caso seja usuário Windows, pode contar com o [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) que possibilita as mesmas funcionalidades.

Comment: Irei testar esse recurso, se funcionar pode resolver o problema pelo menos de forma temporária

Comment: Demorou mas testei, kkkkkkkkk, deu certo e acho que vai resolver meu problema pelo menos temporariamente até eu conseguir fazer da forma que quero via PHP, obg.

Answer (score 2):

Por fora da aplicação, como você tem feito, o ideal seria usar SFTP. Eu particularmente não uso Digital Ocean, mas todo lugar que uso FTP e SFTP dou preferência ao Filezilla.

Estes artigos serão úteis:

- [How To Use SFTP to Securely Transfer Files with a Remote Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sftp-to-securely-transfer-files-with-a-remote-server)
- [How To Use Filezilla to Transfer and Manage Files Securely on your
  VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-filezilla-to-transfer-and-manage-files-securely-on-your-vps)

Já dentro da aplicação, você também pode fazer ela usar o SFTP e fazer o upload, obviamente da um trabalhinho mas ficará bem bacana, certamente.

Aqui você pode usar a extensão do PHP SSH2, mas não vem instalada por padrão, ou usar uma biblioteca externa como a phpseclib.

Tem uma questão no Stackoverflow em Inglês com dois bons exemplos usando ambas soluções, e aproveito e coloco link para um comentário que mostra acessando o servidor acessando as chaves, sem necessidade de senha.

- [How to SFTP with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689540/how-to-sftp-with-php)
- [Autenticação com chave pública](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-connect.php#104758)

Comment: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689540/how-to-sftp-with-php
  - http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-connect.php#104758